# Are answers hiding marketing considered as spam

Tags: discussion, spam

I stumbled upon this answer: [Custom gcc preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545875/custom-gcc-preprocessor/3685576#3685576). While the answer contains some relevant information, the answer tries to promote a specific product, and could be considered as spam. The moderator did not think so. Is it the phrase

> DMS is kind a a big hammer for this task.

That saves the post?

Comment: The profile description of the poster suggests this was already mentioned to them.

Comment: Ira Baxter is a notorious stealth-spammer, a very large proportion of his answers mention his company's products.  Brought up many times at meta before.  The moderators don't know what to do with him, his posts do tend to contain useful other info.  Luckily his products are not very useful, so the better answer does get to the top.

Comment: this is a **seven year old answer**.  user877329, can it possibly concern you that much?

Comment: I find amusing that we want to delete an answer that answers the question, yet it's impossible to get an answer that doesn't answers the question deleted... scratch that, I don't find it amusing, it's depressing.

Comment: Related https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/407/226

Comment: "answers hiding marketing" The answer says "*Our* DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit", I'm not sure Ira is hiding anything.

Answer (score 23):

[We have rules for this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). Minimally, you must:

1. Disclosure your affiliation with the product or service.
2. Provide an answer that is relevant to the question and actually solves the problem.

Ira is doing both of those things here, so this answer is not spam. It *is* self-promotion, but it is not unsolicited self-promotion, which is what is required for something to be spam. pachanga asked the question (the solicitation) and Ira provided a relevant solution that he just so happens to have created.

The only guideline that you might *possibly* say is being violated here is the one that cautions, *"Don't talk about your product / website / book / job too much."* Granted, Ira does tend to post a lot of answers that promote his product(s). This is something that has been discussed previously, *ad nauseam*, and the moderators have been in contact with him about it. As suraj comments, his profile even indicates that he is aware of the problem.

But the answer you have selected here is not emblematic of any sort of a problem, and it is *clearly* not spam. If you disapprove of it or think it is not helpful, feel free to downvote it.

BTW, no, that phrase you quoted has nothing to do with it. If anything, the key phrase is *"Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit is a such a system"*, where he discloses that it is his product and says that it solves the problem. The rest of the answer goes on to explain how. (And then, strangely, conclude that this is a relatively poor solution, but oh well.)

Comment: I wonder if it might be prudent to just get rid of people and their content that evoke such an amount of discussion around whether or not they're spamming the site.

Comment: Unless most of that discussion is ridiculous hand-wringing and navel-gazing. Do we really want to say that people who have designed products or services relevant to a question are not welcome to contribute answers?

Comment: I'd actually say so. But I'm a fervent opponent of advertising on this site, and this site's policy is made by many people and not just one, so that's very open for debate. But yes, I'd actually blanket ban people from recommending their own commercial products (as long as they are commercial).

Comment: That seems like shooting ourselves in the foot, pointlessly robbing users of viable, potentially useful answers. And why would it matter that they are commercial? How is that different from the self-promotional aspect if I wrote a library that I give away for free as long as you credit me for its use? Don't get me wrong, I'm very much against spam, I just don't think this is it. Relevance is the key metric, and considering banning users like Ira is completely absurd when we have legions of users who are repeatedly contributing useless nonsense and no one seems to care.

Comment: Maybe envy has somewhat to do with it. I mean it's no small feat to build up a company and put a product in the market. If it's a product that's aimed at programmers, and it solves real problems actual programmers face, then why not post it on Stack Overflow? But besides envy, the problem I generally have is that their answers read like advertorials and tutorials for their product. Though usually there's some info in the answer on how you would approach it without their product.

Comment: If you're going to recommend a product to solve a problem, the remainder of the answer basically *must* be a tutorial on how to use the product to solve the problem. Otherwise, it isn't a very good answer. This would be equally true whether it's a product you are affiliated with or not.

Comment: @CodyGray A lot would be solved by making it mandatory to also present a competing product with equal or greater prominence as a solution in the same answer. So like, you can advertise, but your answer has to give a viable alternative too. And it's not really envy, I'm just very weary of being advertised to everywhere and these days often the ads are disguised as legit content.

Comment: @Megisch "I'm just very weary of being advertised to everywhere" that's no worse than just reading an answer that doesn't apply to your situation. Clearly Ira's answers about his product still get upvoted, hence they are relevant and useful to some people. Just because they're not helpful to *you* doesn't warrant removing them and depriving others of the information.

Comment: What if there *are* no competing products? What if I recognized a niche because a lot of people ask about doing this thing on Stack Overflow and created a product that does that? That's just an arbitrary standard of legitimacy for answers. If it *wasn't* my product, I wouldn't have to present an alternative. One solution per answer is the normal rule. Frankly, while I understand the "advertising fatigue" sentiment in the abstract, ads are inevitable and aren't going anywhere, so if we can manage to make the ads targeted, relevant, and specific, then [mission accomplished](http://xkcd.com/810).

Comment: @CodyGray In that case, you could pay SE to advertise your product for you, but don't pollute the answers section with ads.

Comment: @Magisch "But I'm a fervent opponent of advertising on this site" You were joking right?  Or were you being bitterly sarcastic about SO?  (Which is, nothing more than, *an advertising company*.  Just like google.)  I appreciate many folks who loathe, despise, advertising  .... loathe and despise companies like google and SO.  Fair enough.  I loathe and despise fast food (say), but .. your comments are kind of confusing.  Like what are you doing on the site ???  :O

Comment: this has made me realize how much I hate advertising!  maybe SO should have the thing where you pay $10 to never see any ads

Comment: I wonder why nobody has flagged Jon Skeet answers for using Joda/Noda time...

Comment: @Tas: Do not edit answers merely to replace "he" with "they".  Thanks.

Comment: @Braiam because neither of those are commercial products?

Comment: @Magisch This is ridiculous. If a paid product was created to solve my problem, I want to know so I can at least try to weigh the cost of buying it vs. the cost of trying to do something else. This will mean some users won't consider it, but how is that a reason to deprive others of information? Restricting useful information is *not* good for SO. The requirements SO has in place are *already* the useful compromise to balance the concerns you have with the fact it's useful info. What *actual* problem would your proposition solve, or is this just some moral crusade against profit?

Comment: @jpmc26 It's a very fundamental conflict of interest. If someone recommends their own product to you, it's no longer an answer, it's a sales pitch. Relevant as it might be, I think SO is not for sales pitches.

Comment: @Magisch This isn't a court of law. It's a problem solving forum. No one is bound to the answer someone suggests. Therefore, it's much better to have as complete information as possible. The "conflict of interest" is required to be declared for consideration; that's enough to grant readers skepticism. What other problem does a "conflict of interest" cause?

Comment: @Magisch: So let's all just stop disclosing our affiliation with any of our products and then none of our posts about them will be sales pitches and there will be no conflict of interest.

Comment: @Magisch Additionally, what problem does having a brief "sales pitch" that describes specifically how a product *solves the problem the OP wants to solve* cause any problems in the first place? Why does the fact it's a "sales pitch" even matter, as long as the sales pitch is *also* an actual answer? Are you just assuming every answer containing a paid product is trying to swindle readers or something?

Comment: @jpmc26 As I said, it can be as relevant and helpful as it wants, it's _still only an advertisement_. There is a place for advertisements on SO, and it's on the side bar or top bar, after paying for the spot, of course.

Comment: @Magisch That's where you're wrong, as my previous comment pointed out. It can also be *an answer*, having sample code and more explanation about the solution than present in the product's documentation, which is not "only an advertisement." No one is suggesting that a raw, "Use my product," with a link is acceptable. The paid ad slots are for people who want to provide *unsolicited* advertisements.

Comment: @jpmc26 When I ask a question, unless I specifically say that I'd like a product that does this, I'm not soliciting an advertisement. If I ask "I'm doing $feature and have $problem, how could I fix this" And someone answers with "Well you could use my paid product in that way to do that" then that is a pretty unsolicited advertisement and also rude towards the question asker in my opinion. In the example in the OP the user is asking about GCC options specifically, so this "answer" is not only not answering the question at all, it's also a brazenly uncalled for advertisement.

Comment: @Magisch: Sounds like you only have a problem with answers recommending paid products in general then, regardless of who's recommending them. It's unsolicited either way.

Comment: @Magisch: Your position is quite contrary to established policies and social norms regarding disclosure and helpfulness of product mentions.  These policies and behavioral norms evolved to allow wanted benefits while restricting unwanted crass commercialism.  Restricting crass commercialism is good, but banning product owners and contributors from ever answering based upon their products would be an unproductive overreaction.

Comment: @Magisch Except that your question isn't just about you. It's about anyone who comes along reading it. You may not want it, and that's fine. That doesn't make it rude to offer a solution you personally wouldn't consider. The fact it happens to involve paid software in no way invalidates it. The fact you begrudge someone the opportunity to help others with their labor for no reason is the rude thing here. If a particular answer doesn't actually answer the question, then downvote it. That doesn't in any way, shape, or form suggest we need to ban all answers with a paid product in them.

Comment: @jpmc26 I accept that I'm in the minority here, which is why I don't go around spam flagging these answers, but I sure wish that was accepted practice. In these days, almost nothing is "innocent" trying to be helpful anymore. We both know why these people post their products, and it's not in good faith. Alas, I still have to assume good faith when I'm voting on their content, but that doesn't prevent me from being grumpy about it :P